# Flink logs not showing up

Tags: logging, apache-flink

**I have a Flink application deployed in the Dev cluster.**

1. And I cannot see the logs anywhere in the Flink dashboard. I was told that they used the default logging level. And what might that be?
2. Where do I reset the logging levels, now that logs are not showing up for the default level?
3. Just to confirm, I added Sout statements exactly as I added logs. And they show up in the Task manager of the application in Kubernetes. So why not logs??
4. In the code, the logs are added as such :

   log.debug("log statement that you want to be displayed");

   Is that the final log level setting? Can I change the log level anywhere?
5. I mention point 4, because, log.debug() is equivalent to log.level().So if I am setting the level = debug here, then why do the log statements into showing up in Flink dashboard, when I run the app in the dev cluster?

Comment: You should find the Flink logs in the kubernetes logs -- have you looked there? In recent versions of Flink I believe the logs are also sent to the dashboard even when running on k8s -- what version of Flink are you using?

Comment: I'm using Flink-1.9.1. 
And only Sout statements must show up in Kubernetes right? The log.debug() statements are supposed to show up in the Flink dashboard right?

Comment: The logs that are currently appearing in Flink dashboard, are the default Flink logs, like jobs running, starting, etc. Not the one I've added in log.debug().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where the logs go in Flink 1.9 when running under kubernetes, but you might need to log into each container and look for them in the logs directory. The kubernetes integration wasn't very mature (or convenient) in 1.9.

Since Flink 1.11 the logs will appear in the Flink web UI, and since 1.12 they're also available via "kubectl logs" by default. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-17166 for more info.

Comment: Actually, I found it in Flink UI. After I changed the log level in code to loh.info as that was what was used in dev cluster. The whole process was confusing, but I somehow managed to get the logs. I still can't run the Flink application locally :(
I found this answer very helpful. Thanks.